# Reviewing first posts: handling answers that are obviously comments

Tags: discussion, review, flags, not-an-answer

While reviewing a first answer that should obviously have been a comment to the original question, I found myself doing three things at once:

1. **Leaving a comment** for the poster, welcoming him to Stack Overflow and explaining, why his answer was not appropriate.
2. Since the answer had no down votes yet, **I downvoted it**, so others immediately see that this answer is worthless.
3. Flag the answer as **not an answer**.

About *1 minute* later I noticed, that my flagging was taken care of, and the answer got deleted.

Is this the usual way how it should be done, or should I have only flagged the answer as **not an answer**? Is the original poster able to see my comment after his answer is deleted, or would my comment be useless in such a case?

---

Somehow related:

- [First Posts. Answers that should be comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152721/first-posts-answers-that-should-be-comments)
- [Do not recommend the “not an answer” flag for conversion to a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214587/do-not-recommend-the-not-an-answer-flag-for-conversion-to-a-comment)

Comment: Sounds fine to me. Deleted posts are visible for the owners, including the comments left on the post before deletion.

Comment: Also, sometimes the post isn't deleted quickly and letting them know with a notification that they shouldn't do that is better than them not knowing why it was deleted.

Comment: In non-obvious cases, a comment can also be helpful to moderators handling the flag. In particular, if you think an answer should be converted to a comment, it's very helpful to include a direct link to the post that you think it should be a comment on. Otherwise, the moderator handling the flag will need to spend extra time trying to guess what the non-answer is replying to. (In fact, [some mods recommend using custom flags instead of NAA for that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214587/do-not-recommend-the-not-an-answer-flag-for-conversion-to-a-comment).)